# Outer loop variable in nested R foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach

I'm trying to use the foreach package in a nested loop, but my inner loop don't recognizes the outer's counter, what m I missing?

```
v3 <- search.compounds.by.mass(100.05,0.5)
foreach(j=2:length(v2)) %:% {
    foreach(i=1:length(v3), .combine=rbind) %dopar% {
        write.table(paste(v3[i], paste(get.reactions.by.compound(v3[i]), collapse=" "), sep=" "), "file1",quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
        write.table(paste(v3[i], paste(get.pathways.by.compounds(v3[i]), collapse=" "), sep=" "), "file2",quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
        v3 <- search.compounds.by.mass(v2[j],0.5)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? Also, what is in the variable v2 (you can use dput(v2) so we can reproduce it)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem is that you are incorrectly applying the `%:%` operator.  It is designed to merge two `foreach` objects, resulting in a single `foreach` object that can be used to repeatedly evaluate whatever expression you supply to it.  So, if you want to use `%:%`, you need to **first** merge the two `foreach()` statements, and **then** use the resulting object to drive a single call to `%do%` (or in your case, `%dopar%`). See **(1)** below for an example.

Alternatively, if you want to nest the two `foreach()` objects, use `%do%` twice, as in **(2)** below.

Either way works, although for parallel jobs I might prefer the one using `%:%`. Your code, though, like **(3)** below, combines elements of the two strategies to produce a hybrid that can't do anything.

```
X <- c("A", "B")
Y <- 1:3

## (1) EITHER merge two 'foreach' objects using '%:%' ...
foreach (j = X, .combine = c) %:% foreach(i = Y, .combine = c) %do% {
    paste(j, i, sep = "")
}
# [1] "A1" "A2" "A3" "B1" "B2" "B3"


## (2) ... OR Nest two 'foreach' objects using a pair of '%do%' operators ...
foreach(j = X, .combine = c) %do% {
    foreach(i = Y, .combine = c) %do% {
        paste(j, i, sep = "")
    }
}
# [1] "A1" "A2" "A3" "B1" "B2" "B3"


## (3) ... BUT DON'T use a hybrid of the approaches.
foreach(j = X, .combine = c) %:% {
    foreach(i = Y, .combine = c) %do% {
        paste(j, i, sep = "")
    }
}
# Error in foreach(j = X, .combine = c) %:% { : 
#   "%:%" was passed an illegal right operand
```

Comment: Good to hear. By the way, if you want to read more about some of the decisions involved in how to structure nested loops, type `vignette("nested")` at the R command line.

Comment: It's painful to note that the vignette shows the right way to do it, and explicitly states it's a binary operator, but it's so easy to make this mistake.